# Xcode / AppleScript / Objective-C (AppDelegate.applescript)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, applescript

I am having a lot of issues following this video tutorial. I'm getting hung up on the AppDelegate.applescript file. [AppleScript Facelift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HE5jFCfkD0w)

Here are the steps I'm taking:

[1. Create a new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5cyD.png)

[2. Then I choose "App"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3yrz.png)

[3.1 Options for interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UASDg.png)

[3.2 Options for Language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TsOhA.png)

4. Save to file location - can't attach an image due to limit

[5. "Template" files created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQbRr.png)

[6. I can add frameworks and libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYh7z.png) *(not sure if this is necessary? im doing things blindly...)*

[7. Then these are the AppDelegate files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY3A8.png) *(note- I can change the identity and type in the top right fields. if I select AppleScript Uncompiled Source, it does not change the extension)*

I've tried creating a new "blank file" and saving it as AppDelegate.applescript, but I don't think this is working. Can someone point me in the right direction???

I've been working on an AppleScript project which works with my Apple Music. Someone mentioned I should look into Objective-C AppleScript, but this is making no sense. I think my end goal is having a window that allows more flexibility with input...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is for the regular (Objective-C/Swift) App template - for an AppleScript project you need to use the AppleScript App template (note that this template is not included in Xcode 14).  AppleScriptObjC can also be used from the Script Editor, although you will have to do the UI stuff manually.

Comment: @red_menace seriously, thank you (again!!). is there a way to install an extension or something for that template? or is there another workaround? I'm currently downloading Xcode 13, so hopefully that includes it?

Comment: It does, I've also placed a copy on my GitHub page.

Comment: Oh great! Im looking at your website now, and it has TONS of helpful functions I will be stealing! What's your GitHub page? I don't see it on your profile

Comment: It is their weird icon/logo next to the website link.  I've been cleaning up some Cocoa-AppleScript UI handlers to add, so if there is something specific you are looking for, you can contact me off-list.

Comment: im a tool, but wym off-list? I don't see a way to DM you here or on GitHub

Comment: There isn't, just putting that out there to avoid using comments, which aren't really the place, unless related to a post.

Comment: Oh I see. How can I contact you directly?

Comment: There is an email address on my website pages.

Comment: Given that the AppleScript app template is gone in Xcode 14 and AppleScript itself is being slowly wound down, the sensible thing is to write your app in Swift and only call into AppleScript (via AppleScript-ObjC) when you need to [control another application](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC). Depending on your needs you should also look into MusicKit and other media frameworks for accessing music resources directly.

Comment: hey @has, any chance we could speak directly? I got ur app working [ https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC ]
which is PERFECT for what I need. But I do have a few questions since im so new to swift. Ive also been doing tutorials, so I might not be completely lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer: I was taking a very dated approach to this and asking the wrong question.@has's suggestion to look at his project [Swift-AppleScriptObjC](https://github.com/hhas/Swift-AppleScriptObjC) is exactly what I needed.